# How can messages be cleared from the built-in tile notification center in band 2

Tags: microsoft-band

I see from the Band SDK that a windows phone app can only use the client tile manager to access its own tile pages. The SDK also indicates that a tile can keep up to 8 message notifications in a FIFO queue.

I would assume that the built-in tile does the same thing, since when it displays a notification sent to my windows phone app - it hangs around until it gets kicked out.

I see that an existing WP app is able to clear the whole queue from the notification center without any dummy notifications showing up on the phone (like to clear the queue)  Does this take some privileged API access?

or if you're clever enough you win the prize?
thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

The Tiles built into the Band's firmware do not, necessarily, have the same behavior or limitations as custom Tiles created by applications via the Band SDK, so you have to be careful when making comparisons.  Nor can the built-in Tiles be manipulated by applications via the Band SDK.

To which application are you referring that can clear the notification Tile?

Comment: The wp 8.1 app 'Clear My Band' - i did try it and it not only can it clear the notification tile of its messages but from other built-in tiles as well. Thank you for addressing my question - as sometimes one wonders whether certain apps have inside knowledge. I haven't tried it - but I thought one approach would be to get hold of the parent container to my tile - then traverse the visual tree looking for other sibling tiles and then grab their guid's - i suppose that would be some security hole for sure.. but somehow that app manages to clear the tile's notifications.

Comment: I did some looking around and I didn't find any window type handle based on the band interfaces available to my app. I did find that after using the app in question to clear the band's built in notification tile of messages - the tile did show to be empty but then it would not receive any new messages until I used the Health app to disable 'Notifications' - save - and then re-enable and then it started to work again. I thought the app was somewhat privileged because it shows no 'contact' information on the app itself that I could see.